# Unable to Upload file with filename with different extention in php

Tags: php

Unable to Upload file with filename with different extention in php

```
echo basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 //  header("Location: EHP_Configuration.html");
 } else{
  //   header("Location: EHP_Configuration.html");
        echo "Notdone";
 }
```

i have verified that on Echo it show proper filename

But move_upload give me "Notdone"

Regards

Comment: Can you format your code using the code button on the toolbar?

Comment: @new - that's a much better way of asking a question than your last go! Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Have you got error_reporting on? If so check to see if a warning is thrown, if there is no warning and you're just getting FALSE retruned then PHP doesn't think the file is a valid uploaded file (done via PHPs HTTP POST) if you are getting a warning as well as a return value of FALSE this should give some indication as to what the problem with moving the file is.

Comment: File i am trying to upload....is valid file and also i want user to get restrcted to that file extension only
it work for xlx extension

Answer (score 0):

May be you have missed slash here:

```
$target_path . '/' . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

I miss it all the time :)

Comment: What's the value of $target_path ?